# Let G be a k-connected graph and u,v1,..,vk vertex ,prove that G contains an uvi path for evey i (1 <= i <= k) such that every 2 paths intersect at u.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I'm having a problems to prove this statement (This the full statement):

- Let $G$ be a $k$-connected graph, and let $u, v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k$ be $k + 1$ distinct vertices in $G$. Prove that $G$ contains a $uv_i$ path for every $i$ ($1 \le i \le k$) such that every $2$ paths intersect at $u$.

I have the idea that it is correct, but I've used Merge's Theorem and still can't get the proof.

I'm new to Graph Theory, but I'm trying to do my best.

Could you give any help/hints?

Thank you.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Sorry I'm new on this ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are on the right track with Menger's theorem. I would suggest adding an extra vertex $w$ and connect it to vertices $v_1, \dots, v_k$. Observe that this graph is still $k$-connected, as we must remove at least $k$ vertices to disconnect $w$.

Now apply Menger's theorem for vertices $u$ and $w$: the size of a minimum $u$-$w$ cut is equal to the maximum number of edge-disjoint $u$-$w$ paths. The size of a minimum $u$-$w$ cut is at least $k$, since the graph is $k$-connected, which now implies the statement that we needed to prove.

Comment: Oh thak you, I think I just solved!